# Exportar a Excel y ods desde asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy tratando de exportar a dos formatos de *Excel*, (a xsls y a ods) desde una base de datos con asp.net mvc pero no he podido ya que me da un error y me dice que el archivo no existe o esta dañado, el código es el siguiente:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Archivo.xlsx");
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

Pero si lo uso de esta manera si me funciona:

```
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=Archivo.xls");

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
```

Este código solo me deja exportar a formato xls (Excel 2007 o anterior)
pero necesito el .xlsx y el ods.

¿Alguien que me pueda ayudar y me diga como puedo exportar desde asp.net a esos dos formatos?

Answer (score 0):

El contentType de los xls lo tienes bien, es **application/vnd.ms-excel**.
Pero el contentType de los xlsx es **application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet** .
Prueba a cambiar el contentType.

De todas formas no pones el código que utilizas para exportar a esos formatos, asi que no puedo ayudarte mucho más.
Si lo que haces es el viejo truco que devolver un html y poner el contentType para que sea el Excel el que lo convierta, te debería funcionar. Pero siempre dará errores de que no es un archivo de Excel y que tienes que convertirlo.